# Why is not possible to combine 'continue' keyword in expression?

Tags: php, loops

Why this is not possible to accomplish?

```
foreach($arr as $k => $v)
{
   if($condition) { $obj->myMethod() && continue; }
}
```

After `$obj->myMethod()` gets evaluated then the keyword `continue` is evaluated (executed), resulting in skipping the current iteration.

**EDIT**: i'm asking this because something like:

```
if($error) { $log->fatal('Something weird happened.') && continue; }
```

is single line and self-explanatory.

Comment: Why not `if ($condition && $obj->myMethod()) continue;` ?

Comment: @zerkms for example because `$obj->myMethod()` can do some stuff and return a `string` value.

Comment: then `$obj->myMethod() && continue` just makes no sense

Comment: @zerkms it does not make sense only because i'm evaluating a string value (true if not empty). Semantically no sense? See my edits.

Comment: `if ($error && $log->fatal('Something weird happened.') continue;` or `if($error) { $log->fatal('Something weird happened.'); continue; }` huh?

Comment: `self-explanatory.` --- it doesn't become more self-explained only because you've replaced `;` with `&&`. Even more - in php `;` is used to separate expressions. So `bla(); bla()` is much more self-explained in php just because of the syntax basics.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`continue` is a statement not an expression.
And never the twain shall meet.

You can't put a statement in an expression.  (What would `echo false && continue;` print?)

Instead, use an `if`, which can contain statements.

Comment: I would have used "language construct" or "control structure" over the broad word "statement." Also, your last sentence is just a tad confusing/misworded.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot evaluate continue as a condition.  The continue keyword does not work the same way as in other languages. In PHP, depending on context continue and break can be somewhat synonymous, consider this construct:

```
 <?php
  switch ($months)
  {
    // start with vowels
    case 'august':
      break;
    case 'april':
      continue;     // exactly the same as "break" !!!
    default:
      return 'OK';
  }

  throw new StartsWithVowelException('Months with vowels are creepy');

?>
```

While we are on the topic, the `break` and `continue` keywords  have a feature in PHP that make them a bit more interesting and powerful than their peers in other languages.

Both can be given a numerical argument when used in a loop that indicates how many loops to continue through or break out of. For example, here is an example that  restarts the execution of an outer loop from within an inner one::

```
<?php

  //
  // verify that each sub array contains the given value
  //
  $lowerval = strtolower($value);

  foreach ($TwoDArray as $otherArray)
  {
    foreach ($otherArray as $value)
    {
      if (strtolower($value) == $lowerval)
      {
        // we found the value -- this one definitely has it.
        continue 2;
      }
    }

    // if we've reached here, then the inner loop doesn't have the
    // value.  ¡aiiee!
  }

?>
```

Hope this helps you out with these 2 constructs, good-luck.

Comment: Notes: 1) I think the only place you'll really find continue used within a switch block is when the switch block is also contained within another loop, using continue to skip the rest of that iteration as well. In a switch block alone, it would not make much semantic sense. 2) I wouldn't say they are synonymous, so much as just achieving the same result with different methods. Using continue within a switch block still achieves the same effect of continuing to the next iteration, but a switch block only ever has one "iteration" in the first place. Good explanation though.

Comment: @animuson Hey! Thanks for the feedback, but to be honest these are code examples I found in some Russian pastebin or *who knows*.

I should of mentioned it is not production code, only meant as an example because continue is truly not meant to be used in the way it is in that first code example.

Answer (score 0):

`continue` is a statement. In PHP a statement and an expression are two different things, statements cannot be evaluated because they do not by nature return true or false which is a requirement for evaluation in PHP.

In PHP you'd have to do something like:

```
if(test()) continue;
```

Comment: You can't use `continue` outside of a looping structure, it will throw a fatal error.

Comment: Although animuson has a good point, I'll give you back (a free) upvote for having had a go at it.  Keep at it, your contribution was a very nice shot. *Just double-check your code examples, code-sharks are known to hang around here. Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you, stef. I'll try being more sure that what I suggest will work in the future. :)